# Formula that removes values based on 3 first characters?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm asking if it's possible in [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) to write a formula that

- takes a cell value and get 10 values from right to left (in order to remove unwanted values as for example +58, 58, 0)
- and then get the first three values in order to remove unwanted once again

For example, see the sample data below:

> ```
> 04145885607
> 04145894589
> 04145920307
> 04145930676
> 04145945235
> 04145971623
> 584146316092
> +584146317534
> 00584146318088
> 4146337864
> 4146361075
> 4146400205
> 4146415696
> 4146416643
> ```

- I need to remove in first values like **+58**, **58**, **0** all at the start of the string
- then compare the first three values and leave for example those who have `41`4 or `424`

Is that possible in Excel?

Comment: Easiest way to do this is SEARCH for 414 or 424 and then use MID to select characters to end of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED

Here is a slightly more complicated formula that will work if you have both "414" and "424" mixed in the column of text strings. Note that the FIND function will also work in place of the SEARCH function in the formula.

```
  =MID(A1,IFERROR(SEARCH("414",A1),0)+IFERROR(SEARCH("424",A1),0),99)
```

Another variation that will work as well:

```
  =MID(A1,IFERROR(SEARCH("414",A1),IFERROR(SEARCH("424",A1),0)),99)
```

An interesting alternative that works if you have a list of values that could be a match is the following array formula:

```
  =MID(A1,MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH($D$1:$D$3,A1),99)),99)
```

To use it, you set up a list of the values to look for (I used cells D1:D3 as shown below) and then reference that list in the SEARCH (or FIND) function. As an array formula, it needs to be entered with the <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination.

[image: array formula]

All of these formulas return a #VALUE! error if the search strings are not found.

Comment: I try to use your latest formula but can't, when I press key combination nothing happen, I'm using Office 2013

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
=MID(A1,FIND("414",A1),99)
```

Or with 424 in the mix

```
=MID(A1,IF(ISERROR(FIND("414",A1)),FIND("424",A1),FIND("414",A1)),99)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @teylyn, I use your formula and isn't working in some cases as for example this numbers, `4241429336, 4241431502, 4241448989, 4241456903, 4241457086` the cause can't find it, can you take a look?

Comment: @teylin I also found those two, `582424212955` => `424212955` (formula for this is `=MID(A840,IF(ISERROR(FIND("414",A840)),FIND("424",A840),FIND("414",A840)),99)`) and this other too `02124142957 
` => `4142957 
` and formula is `=MID(A841,IF(ISERROR(FIND("414",A841)),FIND("424",A841),FIND("414",A841)),99)`, it's something wrong?